# Delete array object within Mongodb Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to pass a delete request from my front end to delete an array object from my mongodb collection. From working through my attempt the network log is showing that the correct deleteQuestion function is being called in my back end as the message "Question deleted successfully." is being return with a 200 code.

However nothing from my database is actually being deleted. Please see the below function that is processing the request. I have also checked the correct id is being sent in the header and it is so was hoping the back end would use this correct id to find and remove only the question from the array in the Quiz.

```
export const deleteQuestion = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).send(`No post with id: ${id}`);

    await Quiz.findByIdAndRemove(id);

    res.json({ message: "Question deleted successfully." });
}
```

MongoDB schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const QuizSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    quizName: String,
    quizTheme: String,
    shortDescription: String,
    longDescription: String,
    question: [{
        question1: String,
        question2: String,
        question3: String,
        question4: String,
        answer: String
    }]
})

const Quiz = mongoose.model("Quiz", QuizSchema, "quiz")

export default Quiz
```

Comment: So what is desired behaviour? Do you want to delete the `Quiz` with id `req.params.id` or you want to delete a question?

Comment: I am looking to only delete the question with the question id being passed with id req.params.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete an item inside an array you need to use `$pull` update operator. You can read about it here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

In your particular case it can look in the following way.

```
 await Quiz.updateOne({}, { $pull: { question: { _id: id}}});
```

It should work, but I would advise you to use

```
await Quiz.updateOne({ _id: quizId }, { $pull: { question: { _id: id}}});
```

Because it may be that `id` won't be unique in the whole collection if you are using some kind of custom logic to create question ids, and in that case, you can delete such question in every quiz. Providing `quizId` allows to filter off quizzes that you are not interested in.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice, currently working through my first MERN build at the moment and a lot to try learn in a short time for a work project, much appreciated.